# Font weight for votes/answers/views on question list is too light

Tags: bug, design

I really like the new design, but I think the font weight for the vote/answer/view counts in the question list is a little light. This is particularly pronounced when the question is marked as answered. Here’s a screenshot:

[image]

Maybe it’s just me, but I find that “1” quite difficult to read. I think a slightly heavier font weight (at least for answered questions, if nothing else) is in order.

For comparison, here’s a similar screenshot from TeX.sx:

[image]

I find those counts much easier to read at a glance.

It also looks like that green box is supposed to be a bit taller, to add a bit of padding on the top of the “1”, like the three other sides.

Safari and Chrome, OS X

Comment: IE has the same issue.

Comment: I would add to this, the contrast is not so great for the scores of related questions on the right hand pane ->.